# Net-SNMP - Compiling in a new MIB module, without Compiling the whole SNMP Agent

Tags: c++, c, compilation, makefile, net-snmp

I´m about to writing my own Net-SNMP MIB Module and was wondering if it is necessary to compile the Whole Agent, since it takes about 5 Minutes. I´m experimenting a lot so i could save hours each day if i could speed up this process.

The Process of doing this, as described in the SNMP-Tutorial "Writing a MIB Module" subitem [Compiling in your new MIB module](http://www.example.com/),
is to execute the `./configure` file with the parameter
`--with-mib-modules="customMibModule"` followed by the conventional `$ make` and `$ make install` routines.

This customMibModule is my MIB-Module, located in the agent/mibgroup/ folder of the Net-SNMP Agend Source Code.

Thank you all in advanced!

Comment: Check out [this question][1]. In my case it was dynamic linking.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898780/add-new-mib-master-agent/27648381

Answer (score 0):

This link might be helpful.
http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/tutorial/tutorial-5/toolkit/demon/index.html
Here the agent is not compiled, but snmp subagent is created (containing the required MIB source files) which then will interact with the agent and register's the MIB.

Answer (score 0):

You can just `make` and `make install` SNMP agent and then link your code with libraries that just created. To add new MIBs to your SNMP agent, use `mib2c` program. it should be in source codes of net-snmp. This program converts MIB files to .c and .h files that you can use them and customize them.