# snmpget “No such object available on this agent at this OID”

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, net-snmp

I have been working on trying to get a value with a custom MIB through SNMP following this [tutorial](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/TUT:Writing_a_MIB_Module). I'm using net-snmp 5.7.3. I have used this [MIB](https://github.com/winlibs/net-snmp/blob/master/mibs/DISMAN-PING-MIB.txt) along with the corresponding [codes](https://github.com/winlibs/net-snmp/tree/master/agent/mibgroup/disman/ping) with [this](https://github.com/winlibs/net-snmp/blob/master/agent/mibgroup/disman/ping-mib.h).

My setup: I have two VM's, both `Ubuntu 16`, one is *snmp-server* with IP:192.168.5.20 and the other *snmp-agent* with IP:192.168.5.21.

I did `MIBS=ALL` and `export MIBS`. On the agent, I have successfully compiled my MIB and got the expected output. My code files are in the path `/home/snmp-agent/Desktop/proj/net-snmp-5.7.3/agent/mibgroup/`. I reconfigure mthe net-snmp like this:

```
./configure --with-mib-modules="pingCtlTable pingResultsTable pingProbeHistoryTable"
make
make install
```

Everything worked fine. And when I do `snmptranslate` on the agent I get:

```
root@snmpagent:~# snmptranslate -On DISMAN-PING-MIB::pingResultsTable
.1.3.6.1.2.1.80.1.3
root@snmpagent:~# snmptranslate -On DISMAN-PING-MIB::pingCtlTable
.1.3.6.1.2.1.80.1.2
root@snmpagent:~# snmptranslate -On DISMAN-PING-MIB::pingProbeHistoryTable
.1.3.6.1.2.1.80.1.4
```

Output on the server, when I do this:

```
snmpget -v2c -c public 192.168.5.21 sysDescr.0
SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0 = STRING: Linux snmp-agent 4.10.0-33-generic #37~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 11 14:07:24 UTC 2017 x86_64
```

But when I run `snmpget`, from the server, I get this error for all the three:

```
snmpget -v2c -c public 192.168.5.21 DISMAN-PING-MIB::pingCtlTable.0
DISMAN-PING-MIB::pingCtlTable = No Such Object available on this agent at this OID
```

Output when specified the OID's:

```
snmpget -v2c -c public 192.168.5.21 .1.3.6.1.2.1.80.1.2
DISMAN-PING-MIB::pingCtlTable = No Such Object available on this agent at this OID
```

> NOTE: I have already seen these posts with no luck for me.
>   [add new mib master agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898780/add-new-mib-master-agent)
>   [snmpget-no-such-object...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29823789/snmpget-no-such-object-available-on-this-agent-at-this-oid) and [snmpget-returns-no-such-object...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20974249/snmpget-returns-no-such-object-available-on-this-agent-at-this-oid)

**UPDATE 2:**

When I do `snmpwalk` from the server, I get:

```
root@snmp-server:# snmp-server:# snmpwalk -v 2c -c ncs -m DISMAN-PING-MIB 192.168.5.22 .1.3.6.1.2.1.80
DISMAN-PING-MIB::pingObjects.0 = INTEGER: 1
DISMAN-PING-MIB::pingFullCompliance.15.46.49.46.51.46.54.46.49.46.50.46.49.46.56.48 = STRING: "/bin/echo"
DISMAN-PING-MIB::pingMinimumCompliance.15.46.49.46.51.46.54.46.49.46.50.46.49.46.56.48 = ""
DISMAN-PING-MIB::pingCompliances.4.15.46.49.46.51.46.54.46.49.46.50.46.49.46.56.48 = ""
DISMAN-PING-MIB::pingCompliances.5.15.46.49.46.51.46.54.46.49.46.50.46.49.46.56.48 = INTEGER: 5
DISMAN-PING-MIB::pingCompliances.6.15.46.49.46.51.46.54.46.49.46.50.46.49.46.56.48 = INTEGER: 1
DISMAN-PING-MIB::pingCompliances.7.15.46.49.46.51.46.54.46.49.46.50.46.49.46.56.48 = INTEGER: 1
DISMAN-PING-MIB::pingCompliances.20.15.46.49.46.51.46.54.46.49.46.50.46.49.46.56.48 = INTEGER: 4
DISMAN-PING-MIB::pingCompliances.21.15.46.49.46.51.46.54.46.49.46.50.46.49.46.56.48 = INTEGER: 1
DISMAN-PING-MIB::pingIcmpEcho.1.15.46.49.46.51.46.54.46.49.46.50.46.49.46.56.48 = ""
DISMAN-PING-MIB::pingIcmpEcho.2.15.46.49.46.51.46.54.46.49.46.50.46.49.46.56.48 = ""
DISMAN-PING-MIB::pingIcmpEcho.3.15.46.49.46.51.46.54.46.49.46.50.46.49.46.56.48 = INTEGER: 1
DISMAN-PING-MIB::pingIcmpEcho.4.15.46.49.46.51.46.54.46.49.46.50.46.49.46.56.48 = INTEGER: 0
DISMAN-PING-MIB::pingMIB.4.1.2.15.46.49.46.51.46.54.46.49.46.50.46.49.46.56.48.1 = ""
```

So accordingly when I follow the output of `snmpwalk`, I get:

```
root@snmp-server:# snmpget 192.168.5.22 DISMAN-PING-MIB::pingFullCompliance.15.46.49.46.51.46.54.46.49.46.50.46.49.46.56.48
DISMAN-PING-MIB::pingFullCompliance.15.46.49.46.51.46.54.46.49.46.50.46.49.46.56.48 = Wrong Type (should be INTEGER): STRING: "/bin/echo"
```

I don't understand why I have such a long OID? **What is pingFullCompliance.15.46.49.46.51.46.54.46.49.46.50.46.49.46.56.48** ? Where am I going wrong? Can anyone please point me in the right direction... Thank you.

Comment: I have the same issue. Is it resolved ?

Comment: Unfortunately Nope!